# Click on a button that only contains an icon with PHP Unit and Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

For my acceptance test

```
$this->visit("/tournaments")
        ->see($this->tournaments)
        ->click(MyLinkWithIcon);
...

<a href="http://laravel.dev:8000/article/delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><b><i class="icon-minus22 mr-5"></i></b></a>
```

I don't know what to put as click parameter so that it detects that I clicked the font awesome icon link that delete my article.

Any idea???

Comment: Please define "click parameter"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your link an id and use that as your parameter:

```
<a id="icon_button" href="http://laravel.dev:8000/article/delete" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right"><b><i class="icon-minus22 mr-5"></i></b></a>


$this->visit("/tournaments")
    ->see($this->tournaments)
    ->click('icon_button');
```

Comment: and how can I do when I have 10 buttons "delete" in the same page? Is there anything better than concatenate id?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Each button will need a unique id and you would need to run the `click` method for each button

Comment: In the case I have a list with 10 items with 10 icons to delete, must I do id="delete_$userId", or is there a lighter way to proceed?

Comment: I mean alter my code just for a test unit to work doesn't convince me too much